# Auditing logged in user with delete trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We have an audit option in our application, where we are auditing the deleted records from a table using **AFTER DELETE ON** trigger.

*Problem description :*
The problem that we face here is, we need to log the person who has deleted the record. We could not get id of the person deleted the record anywhere from the database as its not present. Its coming from the web application. My question is there anyway to get the name or id of the person who has logged into the web application in the database side.

We are using oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using dbms_session package.Using the package you can set and get values.Hence , during the login to your application , you can set the value and finally while on delete trigger execution , get this and insert into the audit table.

This might come handy - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_session.htm

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. have a question regd that. Can this approach handle concurrent access of the application by more than one users?

Comment: Definitely it can.You can try it by logging these values into a table at transaction level and verify the same.